# Can I invoke a web service using call mediator in wso2 esb?

Tags: web-services, csv, wso2-esb

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name=SEQUENCE trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <iterate expression=EXPRESSION sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property expression="$body/*" name="Test within iterate"/>
                </log>
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="POST" uri-template=URI TEMPLATE
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
                <log>
                    <property name="After CALL" value="response"/>
                </log>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="$body/*" sequence="OutSequenceforData"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
            xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
    </aggregate>
    <send/>
    <log level="full">
        <property expression="$body/*" name="After Aggregate" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
</sequence>`
I am trying to invoke a web service using call mediator. But I do not see any log about the call in the wso2 logs. The goal is to display the data from a file in the web service.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your proxy? And maybe explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not using a proxy service for this development. Following are the steps I have developed:Using an inbound endpoint to pick up a file from local directory, calling a sequence which iterates through the data from the file. This data I am wanting to Post on a web service call. To achieve this, I am using a call mediator which is pointing to a HTTP Endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, after the Call mediator put a Log mediator.

```
<log level="full" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the log mediator after call. But I only see the records split by the iterate mediator. The call mediator is not functioning after the iterate. Is there a need to use Aggregate mediator after iterate or am I missing out any other step?

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your synapse configs.

Comment: Also answering your question, yes you need aggregate mediator.